# How can I see which edition of windows 8 is installed on a hdd image without starting it?

Tags: windows-8, vhd

I have a `.vhdx` image of a installed Windows 8 and I need to know which edition is installed on that image.

Because I encounter the same issue described in this question: [Getting Windows 8 System Image Recovery to recognize my backup](https://superuser.com/questions/507133/getting-windows-8-system-image-recovery-to-recognize-my-backup#comment744032_507133) I cannot restore that image and see there what edition is hold on that image.

What files do I need to inspect on that image (i can mount it on another win8 pc) and  see which edition of windows 8 is installed without starting it?

Comment: You can't determine the license type of a windows installation by just looking at the installation itself. There is no special file that determines what version of a specific version of Windows your using.

Comment: @Ramhound I found a RHDSetup.log in which contains among other info the first two lines `OS Information [WINMAJOR Number] = 6` `OS Information [WINMAJOR String] = 6.2`, maybe this is the file or maybe there is other file that contains some info on the edition.

Comment: There is not, the file you found, isn't even created by Windows but some other program. In order to figure out the information you want you have to get the image into a bootable state and check the registry.  If you have access to a working Windows 8 installation with Hyper-V support you could simply use that.

Comment: @Ramhound Because it's _impossible_ to load the registry unless the machine is booted, right? http://i.imgur.com/YgIzSiU.png

Comment: @Tanner - I **never** it wasn't possible to load the registry hive when the system isn't booted. You seem to have an answer to the author's question. The image would still have to be able to be mounted. If you have a possible answer then post it. I won't get into a discussion with you on this subject.